# Uneven distribution of load in linux cpu cores

Tags: linux, cpu, cpu-usage

I have a virtual linux server that has 8 cores. I added an additional 4 cores without rebooting the server, and I saw the additional CPUs but they are still offline:

[image]

I found a way to make the additional CPUs "online" without rebooting the server:

`echo 1 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu8/online`

`echo 1 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu9/online`

`echo 1 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu10/online`

`echo 1 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu11/online`

After monitoring the cpu usage for a few minutes, I noticed that the additional CPUs are not getting enough load:

[image]

Is this normal? Or do I really have to reboot my server in order for the load to be distributed evenly across all the CPU cores?